# SQL Join fetching same name row

Tags: php, sql, join

I've got 2 tables, a join, a `SELECT *`. Both tables contain the field `id`, but I need to explicitly access one in this way:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  #__docman as d JOIN #__users u ON d.dmmantainedby = u.id WHERE d.catid = 5 ORDER BY d.id ASC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->id ; 
}
```

I tried

```
echo $row->d.id;
```

That didn't work..I know I could technically change my SELECT to call for the id's and use aliases but, there are a lot of fields I am fetching, hence the `*`. Is there another way?

Comment: WE'd need to know what library you use to access database. From what I can see it's neither mysqli nor PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use aliases, the query stays short if you duplicate the data:

```
"SELECT *, d.id as did, u.id as uid FROM  #__docman as d JOIN #__users u ON d.dmmantainedby = u.id WHERE d.catid = 5 ORDER BY d.id ASC"
```

And then:

```
$row->did
$row->uid
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *, d.id AS id_alias FROM ...` ? This will select duplicate columns but will still be pretty short query.